# FSK and IQ modulation

Tags: modulation, demodulation, fsk, quadrature, frequency-modulation

I am having trouble understanding the FSK modulation process. There are many ways of demodulating the FSK signal.

- What is the advantage of performing the FSK using IQ modulation?
- How to demodulate the FSK signal?
- Does the FSK signal look triangular wave or sinewave?

Answer (score 7):

> What is the advantage of performing the FSK using IQ modulation?

1. You only need one RF oscillator operating at a single frequency, instead of having 2 (or more in the case of M-ary FSK) oscillators operating at separate frequencies for each bit/symbol.
2. Since you only have one oscillator, you don't have to worry about discontinuities in the phase of the transmitted RF signal, like this:

[image]

Sharp discontinuities contain high frequency which widens the bandwidth of the signal. With I/Q modulation you'll have a much easier time producing a continuous-phase FSK signal (CPFSK).

> How to demodulate the FSK signal?

First lets assume we are trying to demodulate a simple FSK signal where the center frequency is $f_c$, a '1' is represented by the frequency $f_c+\Delta f$, and a '0' is represented by the frequency $f_c-\Delta f$.

Before IQ sampling, you tune your RF front end receiver to $f_c$. Then when you sample you have a baseband I/Q representation of the signal, centered around 0 Hz. The only thing to do is figure out if you have a positive frequency (+$\Delta f$) or negative frequency (-$\Delta f$). The easiest way to do that is to monitor the **change in phase** of the baseband IQ signal. A positive phase change corresponds to a positive frequency, and a negative phase change corresponds to a negative frequency.

So monitor the phase (the angle of $I + jQ$) and watch how it changes over one symbol period. Positive change = '1', negative change = '0'.

> Does the FSK signal look triangular wave or sinewave?

If you're talking about the RF signal, it looks like a sinewave of varying frequency.

If you're talking about baseband IQ signal, it also looks sinusoidal, but with a bunch of phase shifts, like this (blue = I, orange = Q):

[image]

In this particular example, a '1' corresponds to a phase change of $+\pi/2$, and a '0' corresponds to a phase change of $-\pi/2$.

Answer (score 4):

> There are many ways of demodulating the FSK signal

Indeed!

> What is the advantage of performing the FSK using IQ modulation?

Depends. Generally, IQ is the only shape you have your signal in, so using that is not much of a question – a  direct downconversion system has IQ signals, and that's what you'll use. Using such a system has a lot of advantages, but I'm not going to go into much detail here, because that would leave the scope of your FSK question.

> How to demodulate the FSK signal?

To cite *you*: There are many ways! You could go with a filter bank, you can go with a DFT / FFT (which is, by the way, a special filter bank, if you will so), you can go with the $\angle\frac{s[n]}{s[n-1]}$ to give you a measure of the angular velocity (==frequency) of a digital signal $s$, you can multiply and integrate with different sines (which is pretty close to the filterbank method, again)...

> Does the FSK signal look triangular wave of sinewave?

This sentence doesn't make sense.